# Saving the output of a cell as a txt file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, random, jupyter-notebook

I would very much like to save the output of the last cell in a txt file.

```
 q = [rng.next () for _ in range (0, 25000000)]
```

I know I can use pandas dataframe but I need the txt file to carry out Diehard tests. Is it feasible in a jupyter notebook? Possibly what type of data do I need to carry out the [Dieharder Suite](http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) ?

I am almost sure that once I did something like that unfortunately I do not remember how, and I can not find a clear answer

Below is the code of my LCG random number generator:

```
import numpy as np

class LCG(object):

    UZERO: np.uint32 = np.uint32(0)
    UONE : np.uint32 = np.uint32(1)

    def __init__(self, seed: np.uint32, a: np.uint32, c: np.uint32) -> None:
        self._seed: np.uint32 = np.uint32(seed)
        self._a   : np.uint32 = np.uint32(a)
        self._c   : np.uint32 = np.uint32(c)

    def next(self) -> np.uint32:
        self._seed = self._a * self._seed + self._c
        return self._seed

    def seed(self) -> np.uint32:
        return self._seed

    def set_seed(self, seed: np.uint32) -> np.uint32:
        self._seed = seed

    def skip(self, ns: np.int32) -> None:
        """
        Signed argument - skip forward as well as backward

        The algorithm here to determine the parameters used to skip ahead is
        described in the paper F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride,"
        Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994). This algorithm is able to skip ahead in
        O(log2(N)) operations instead of O(N). It computes parameters
        A and C which can then be used to find x_N = A*x_0 + C mod 2^M.
        """

        nskip: np.uint32 = np.uint32(ns)

        a: np.uint32 = self._a
        c: np.uint32 = self._c

        a_next: np.uint32 = LCG.UONE
        c_next: np.uint32 = LCG.UZERO

        while nskip > LCG.UZERO:
            if (nskip & LCG.UONE) != LCG.UZERO:
                a_next = a_next * a
                c_next = c_next * a + c

            c = (a + LCG.UONE) * c
            a = a * a

            nskip = nskip >> LCG.UONE

        self._seed = a_next * self._seed + c_next


#%%
np.seterr(over='ignore')

a = np.uint32(1664525)
c = np.uint32(1013904223)
seed = np.uint32(1)

rng = LCG(seed, a, c)
q = [rng.next() for _ in range(0, 25000000)]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run below in another cell

```
%%capture cap --no-stderr
print(q)
```

Then again another cell

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cap.stdout)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I found this thread and tried to do it, however the txt file is empty

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. The txt file has 300mb. I was expecting at most 10-15mb. 300mb txt is to much for my computer :D

Comment: do you know how to make each number displayed in a new line, not a decimal point?

Comment: It works for me. If I put everything in the same cell I sometimes need to run the cell twice.

Answer (score 1):

As a small note following `ComplicatedPhenomenon`'s answer, if we need capturing several functions, say `fun1`, `fun2`, `fun3` and write the output to the corresponding files `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, then we can capture with several variables:

Cell 1

```
%%capture cap_f1
fun1()
```

Cell 2

```
%%capture cap_f2
fun1()
```

Cell 3

```
%%capture cap_f3
fun1()
```

Summarize

(I prefer this ugly way because it allows fast line copying)

```
with open('file1', 'w') as f: f.write(cap_f1.stdout)
with open('file2', 'w') as f: f.write(cap_f2.stdout)
with open('file3', 'w') as f: f.write(cap_f3.stdout)
```

or

```
for fname, c in zip(listfilenames, listcaps):
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write(c.stdout)
```